# Spring JPA Specifications Not In Query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

Here the IN criteria query using Spring JPA Specification is working fine. but I don't know how to use "NOT IN"..

So How can i use the NOT IN criteria query using Spring JPA Specifications.

```
SearchSpecification<User> spec = new CommonSpecification<Case>(new SearchCriteria("client.id", Operator.NOT_IN, clientIdList));

@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    Predicate predicate = null;
    switch (searchCriteria.getOperator()) {

    case IN:
        if (searchCriteria.getValue() instanceof List<?>) {
            predicate = getFieldPath(searchCriteria.getKey(), root)
                    .in(((List<?>) searchCriteria.getValue()).toArray());
        }
        break;
    case NOT_IN:
        //What to do???
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }
    return predicate;
}


private Path<Object> getFieldPath(String key, Root<T> root) {
    Path<Object> fieldPath = null;
    if (key.contains(".")) {
        String[] fields = key.split("\\.");
        for (String field : fields) {
            if (fieldPath == null) {
                fieldPath = root.get(field);
            } else {
                fieldPath = fieldPath.get(field);
            }
        }
    } else {
        fieldPath = root.get(key);
    }
    return fieldPath;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `Predicate.not()` method; the code is the same as in the `IN` case, just add `.not()`:

```
case NOT_IN:
    if (searchCriteria.getValue() instanceof List<?>) {
        predicate = getFieldPath(searchCriteria.getKey(), root)
                .in(((List<?>) searchCriteria.getValue()).toArray())
                .not();
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality also works fine..

```
case NOT_IN:
if (searchCriteria.getValue() instanceof List<?>) {
    predicate = criteriaBuilder.not(getFieldPath(searchCriteria.getKey(), root).in(((List<?>) searchCriteria.getValue()).toArray()));
}
break;
```